# Express router multiple handlers issue

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to set up Express routes bound with multiple controllers, of course they're supposed to receive functions, this is what I'm trying:

```
authRouter.get('/login/redirect/:provider', controllers.handleOAuth2Redirect, controllers.jwt);
```

This has sometimes worked, sometimes not, the only changes when works or not are minimal code changes, could be a `require` line, an expression, etc.

This is the error being thrown:

```
Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Object]
```

So following code is the complete **working** controllers file:

```
'use strict';

var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var InstagramStrategy = require('passport-instagram').Strategy;
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;
var facebook_scope = ['email', 'user_about_me','user_friends','publish_actions'];
var passportFacebookOptions = {scope: facebook_scope};

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_FINALCUT_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_FINALCUT_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9248/auth/login/redirect/fb'
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
        return done(null, profile, params);
}));

passport.use(new InstagramStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.INSTAGRAM_FINALCUT_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.INSTAGRAM_FINALCUT_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:9248/auth/login/redirect/ig'
    },
    function (accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done) {
        return done(null, profile, {tokens: {accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken}});       
    })); 

function oauth2ProviderLogin (request,response,next) {

    var provider = request.query.provider;
    switch (provider) {
        case 'fb':
            passport.authenticate('facebook')(request,response,next);
            break;

        case 'ig':
            passport.authenticate('instagram')(request,response,next);
            break;
    }
}

function handleOAuth2Redirect (request,response,next) {

    var provider = request.params.provider;

    switch (provider) {
        case 'fb':
            passport.authenticate('facebook', {session:false})(request,response,next);
            break;

        case 'ig':
            passport.authenticate('instagram', {session:false})(request,response,next);
            break;
    }
}

function jwt (request,response,next) {
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    var token = jwt.sign({auth: request.authInfo}, '623145ca-7749-11e5-8bcf-feff819cdc9f');
    return response.send({user: request.user, auth: token});
}

module.exports = (function() {

    var authController = {
      oauth2ProviderLogin: oauth2ProviderLogin,
      handleOAuth2Redirect: handleOAuth2Redirect,
      jwt: jwt
    };

    return authController;
})();
```

I've literally made it work by changing some lines of the controller functions. But the exports block has always remained the same. Naturally I nede to keep coding but then it stops working.

**An example of something making it to stop working:**

```
'use strict';

var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');  // This makes it fail
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var InstagramStrategy = require('passport-instagram').Strategy;
var OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy;
```

That's it: ***adding a `var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')` will make it fail.***

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

My error is actually silly:

Adding `var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')` because I have a function with same name below:

```
function jwt (request,response,next) {
    var token = jwt.sign({auth: request.authInfo}, '623145ca-7749-11e5-8bcf-feff819cdc9f');
    return response.send({user: request.user, auth: token});
}
```

Just changing the name of any of those will fix the issue.